# SSRS 2017 does not connect to the ORACLE database

Tags: oracle, reporting-services

I migrated my `SSRS reports` from `2008 R2` to `2017`, I have a problem with the connections to my `Oracle 9i database`.

I have created new connections with the `OLE DB connector` for `Oracle` but still the same problem.

the version of the `oracle` client installed on the dev machine is the `10g`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved:

I just installed a new 11g client on my machine 
and correctly configured "tnsnames.ora"